# Send Azure Iot data to azure gen2

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-data-lake-gen2, thingworx

Currently My IOT hub is sending data to storage account gen2 within a folder called rawdata.. But I want to send the data into three folders if it is raw data - send to raw folder, transform data send to transform folder likewise.

Current setting:
[image: Screenshot]
Kindly guide any article.

Thanks
Anuj

Answer (score 1):

The IoT Hub [file upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload) feature is something totally different. So send (and transform) telemetry to a sink like Data Lake Store Gen2, use something like Stream Analytics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/blob-storage-azure-data-lake-gen2-output

In one streaming job you can have multiple outputs with different transformations being applied.

---

edit based on comments:

You can also do simple filtering (but no transformations) using IoT Hub routing queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax

Create different custom endpoints for your storage account (with different paths). Then create different custom routes towards these.

Comment: Need to use IOT hub only since for query and transformation we are already using data bricks. Only requirement is Data is coming from thing Worx need to send data based on some criteria to same storage account but different folders.

Comment: well, then why don't you do your transformation and writing into storage in databricks as well? otherwise, you can look into IoT Hub routing, but that cannot do transformations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#azure-storage-as-a-routing-endpoint

Comment: well, its a good thought but data is coming real time in one folder, & multiple team is working on the same folder in order to read the data from data bricks. So I want to divert the data flow with multiple folder so that appropriate team can have access to there data. IoT Hub must have some message wise filter I need to apply on the data let say if data is for country USA that data will go to USA folder.

Comment: ok, edited my answer. use routing and queries in IoT Hub

Comment: Can we query it in message body if data is coming from thing Worx is in avro format???